# How to filter table rows with search bar in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a search function. I get the data back in the console.log.
Now I want to make sure that when I search something it also filters into the table.
i use React-hooks.

```
function search (searchTerm) {
    const search = getValues("products").filter(
        product =>
            product.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1,
    );
    console.log(search);
}
```

Comment: did you try setting the state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing right but not setting the `filteredProducts` in state

Considering this is your component

```js
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  // your search event handler
  function search (searchTerm) {
    // update search value
    setSearchValue(searchTerm);

    const filtered = getValues("products").filter(
        product =>
            product.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1,
    );

    // set filtered products in state
    setFilteredProducts(filtered);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {searchValue ? (
        // loop over filtered products, so only searched products are shown
      ): (
        // loop over products
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```